# Raid6 hdd compatibility

Tags: raid6, hdd

Looks like the golden day of hard drive failure has come for my raid6 configuration. I have a nas deluxe NDL-2810R, with Silicon Image Inc. SiI 3132 Serial ATA Raid II Controller, and 8 ST5000NM0024-1HT 5TB hdds, in a raid6 configuration. The file system on the raid is Btrfs. The whole system has over 65000 hrs of ontime, and a disk in the raid has reported failure, thus the raid has entered in degraded mode. The Nas functions as an archive, with minimum workload, and it s already over 90% full.

It s my first time dealing with raid failure, and because of cost we don t have any extended guarantee on any part, or support on the device.

I know i need to change the hdd as soon as possible and resilver the hdd, but my problem is the hdd is EOL, they are no longer produced. My question would be, whith what model should i change the faulty one, to assure maximum compatibility? Can i change the mentioned seagate hdd to a bigger 6 tb exos one which is manufactured? Example: ST6000NM019B (from a compatibility pov)

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Steve

Comment: This depends on the controller, but usually this works. Try it, in the worst case it won't accept the new disk and won't start the recovery.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @NikitaKipriyanov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with what model should i change the faulty one, to assure maximum compatibility? Can i change the mentioned seagate hdd to a bigger 6 tb exos one which is manufactured? Example: ST6000NM019B (from a compatibility pov)

When the original model isn't available any more you may select one that:

- uses the same interface (don't mix SAS and SATA)
- runs with the same RPM
- has pretty much the same or a higher sustained transfer rate
- has at least the same size (in doubt, check the exact number of sectors)
- uses the same sector size (512 or 4096 bytes) - in my experience, 512n isn't really required as the stripe size is usually much larger, but that may depend on the exact controller type and its cache

Very often you can deviate somewhat from the above parameters but you shouldn't if you don't know the exact controller behavior.

When you swap out the disk make sure you follow the correct procedure to the letter. And of course, always have a current and tested(!) backup at hand.

Another thing commonly neglected is regular scrubbing/data patrolling. It refreshes weak sectors on the fly and prevents multiple uncorrectable errors to build up. RAID 6 has double redundancy but if there's no regular scrubbing I'd schedule a run before swapping the disk if it hasn't really failed yet. If there's a regular full backup, that counts as scrubbing as well though.